# How can I use Word/DOCX documents inside a report in List & Label

Tags: c#, ms-word, report, document, listlabel

I have seen that it is very easy to use a PDF document in a report of List & Label. However, our users also juggle MS Word documents in everyday life and would like to be able to use these directly in a List & Label report.

Of course, I can try to convert Word files to PDF in the software first, so that you can use them again as PDF objects in the report. But is there also a simple variant that you can directly integrate a Word file in the designer of List & Label - without the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here:

- you can save the Word document as formatted text (RTF) and display this in a Formatted Text object in the design. NB not all Word features are supported by RTF, especially the table support is kind of limited. There's a sample showing the usage of RTF text that can be cloned from [here](https://github.com/combit/ll-samples/tree/main/Microsoft%20.NET/.NET%20Framework%204/WinForms/C%23/RTF%20Sample). The link is for .NET 4.0, there are also Core 3.1 and .NET 5 samples in the repo.
- if Word is installed on the machine rendering the report, you can also use the OLE container object in order to display the contents of your Word document.
- you could write your own DesignerObject that does the job if you already have a component that is capable of rendering the document. [Here's](https://github.com/combit/ll-samples/tree/main/Microsoft%20.NET/.NET%20Framework%204/WinForms/C%23/TX%20Text%20Control%20Sample) a sample implementation that uses the TX Text Control, it can be redone in similar ways for other components.

Comment: Saving into another format like RTF and also loosing Word feature is not really a option. Seems converting to PDF would be better than. But a conversion was not the goal. OLE container sounds not bad... but I'm not sure this will also working within our ASP.NET application - accessing the OLE interface and needs also Word installation on the server. Writing an own designer object doing the necessary rendering sounds really good and I will give it a change. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: If this helps you might consider marking the answer as solution then @DaPeppi